# Angular e2e tests: component is not a known element

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I created an Angular 4 project with `ng cli`, and it runs well in Chrome, but when I try to execute the automated tests I get the following error:

```
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Windows 10 0.0.0) AppComponent should create the app FAILED
        'vm-navbar' is not a known element:
        1. If 'vm-navbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
        2. If 'vm-navbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<vm-navbar></vm-navbar>
        <div class="container">
        "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent.html@0:0

        'router-outlet' is not a known element:
        1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
        2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
        <div class="container">
            [ERROR ->]<router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
```

Where `vm-navbar` is the tag of one of my components. This is the content that I have in my `app.2e2-spec.ts`:

```
import { AppPage } from './app.po';

describe('vmplus App', () => {
    let page: AppPage;

    beforeEach(() => {
        page = new AppPage();
    });

    it('should display welcome message', () => {
        page.navigateTo();
        expect(page.getParagraphText()).toEqual('Welcome to app!');
    });
});
```

I have tried configuring `TestBed` like this, to let it know about my component, but no success so far:

```
import { NavBarComponent } from "../src/app/navbar/navbar.component";
import { TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
...
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ NavBarComponent ]
    });
    page = new AppPage();
});
```

This is what my `navbar.component.ts` file looks like:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthGuard } from "../auth/auth-guard.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'vm-navbar',
    templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './navbar.component.scss' ]
})
export class NavBarComponent
{
    constructor(public authGuard: AuthGuard)
    {
    }
}
```

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't see the module import in spec file

Comment: @Vega Forgot to copy it in the code snippet here, but it was present in my file. Updated the question with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, note the name of the test in the error message is `"should create the app"`, but the test name in the source code is `"should display welcome message"`. The error occurred in a different file I was not aware of: Angular created by default an `app.component.spec.ts` in my component's folder (not in my tests folder).

To solve the problem I added in `app.component.spec.ts` the required components: `NavBarComponent` and `AuthComponent`, and in the `imports` section the `AppRoutingModule` (that is what I called the router in my app):

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavBarComponent } from "./navbar/navbar.component";
import { AuthGuard } from "./auth/auth-guard.service";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        const authGuardStub = {};

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                AppComponent,
                AuthComponent,
                NavBarComponent
            ],
            imports: [
                AppRoutingModule,
                FormsModule,
                HttpModule
            ],
            providers: [
                { provide: AuthGuard, useValue: authGuardStub },
                { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' }
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    it('should create the app', async(() => {
        const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
        expect(app).toBeTruthy();
    }));
});
```